# Outlook 2007 - Move EVERYTHING

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, export, import

I need to move everything about an instance of Outlook 2007 to another computer running Outlook 2007:

- Email account settings / config (not the data file)
- Outlook data files
- Macros
- Special menu customizations

This sounds like a simple question, however literally *every* article give a convoluted description of *how to export a data file*. That doesn't help me. How do I move e-v-e-r-y-t-h-i-n-g?

I tried copying every file and folder from both local and roaming `appdata` dirs, but this still didn't do it. It there stuff tied into the registry? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

There is possible way to do this

**On The Old Machine**

Outlook 2007 is nice enough to put all of its account info for each profile under one key.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\

So, first off, close Outlook if it's running.

To export your Outlook account information, we just need to export that magic key.

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Select the key that you want to save as a file.
3. On the File menu, click Export.
4. In the Export Registry File dialog box, in Save in, click the drive, folder, or network computer and folder where you want to save the hive.
5. In File name, enter a name for the key. (outlook_profile.reg would work great.)
6. In Save as type, make sure it's set as Registration Files (*.reg)
7. Click Save.

Caveats: Every profile on your system under your logon will be exported.

To move your old mail, you'll need to copy your PST file to the new machine.

1. Click Start, Run
2. Type %userprofile%\local settings\application data\microsoft\outlook
3. Click OK
4. In that folder there will be some *.pst files. Copy (don't move!) them to a removable drive or a network share. The one you're most likely concerned with is outlook.pst

**On The New Machine**

First, we need to import the profile information.

1. Double-click the file (outlook_profiles.reg) you exported on the old machine. That will import the new information into the registry. (Simple!)
2. Next, we need to get your data file back over.
3. Click Start, Run
4. Type %userprofile%\local settings\application data\microsoft\outlook
5. Click OK
6. Copy (don't move!) the *.pst files you found on the old machine. The one you're most likely concerned with is outlook.pst

Lastly, we need to set Outlook to use the profile from the old machine.

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open the Mail applet.
3. Click on the Show Profiles button.
4. Choose the profile name that matches the one you used to use from the "Always use this profile" dropdown.
5. Click OK.

Now, when you open Outlook, you should have your old mail and the mail accounts all set up and ready to go.

**Passwords**

Outlook on the new machine will ask you for passwords the first time it does a send/receive on all non-Exchange accounts.

[Microsoft referral link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/exporting-importing-outlook-account-settings/744f06db-34e6-4a4b-b5fb-26cc09368d4a?auth=1)

Comment: Thanks. This however didn't export custom menu buttons that link to macros (it did import the macros themselves). Do you know where this is stored?

Comment: You can refer to this link to import macros http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-backup-and-save-your-outlook-vba-macros/